# SP2010: Help with calculated column for multiple columns

Tags: calculated-column

Sharepoint 2010
Looking for some help here as I'm sure its a simple solution.

I have:
2 Yes/No Columns: DivisionA, DivisionB (I will have a total of 15 divisions but using 2 for an example)
1 Calculated column: Divisions

I would like to have the calculated column return A, B, and/or C depending if any of the yes/no columns were checked.

I have used the following below but it will only return one statement.

```
=IF([DivisionA]=TRUE,"A",IF([DivisionB]=TRUE,"B",""))
```

Comment: So you want the letter of every division where it is true?
Try IF([DivisionA]=TRUE,"A","") & IF([DivisionB]=TRUE,"B","") & ...

Answer (score 0):

tweytjens is right. You have to use the "&" to join the different values (I would rather use &" / "&).